# dojo tree grid loading only 25 rows

Tags: javascript, dojox.grid.datagrid

[image: 1]

In the tree grid which i am using has 60 rows. I am performing a search operation on one of the column in the grid.The search highlights the row with the given search pattern , but only first 25 row is getting searched.

Dojo frame work is used to create this tree grid.

points i noticed while debugging

1.divs are loading when i scroll based on some px value(the first div attached in the picture).
2.only first 25 rows are populating